# In Vala language have a like `Buffer.BlockCopy` or ` BitConverter. ToXXXX () || GetBytes`?

Tags: c#, vala

I am new in Vala and I am trying to rewrite some of my tools that I wrote with c # before. I couldn't find functions like `BitConverter` class or `Buffer.BlockCopy` in Vala like in C #. By the way have a blowfish class for vala?

```cs
Buffer.BlockCopy(stream, offset, workspace, 0, length);

for (int x = 0; x < workspace.length; x += 8)
{
    uint l = BitConverter.ToUInt32(workspace, x + 0);
    uint r = BitConverter.ToUInt32(workspace, x + 4);
    Blowfish_decipher(ref l, ref r);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(l), 0, workspace, x + 0, 4);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(r), 0, workspace, x + 4, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're working over a byte array of some kind. If so, I think the best approach is to create a [`MemoryInputStream`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.MemoryInputStream.html) and then use [`DataInputStream`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.DataInputStream.html) stream over the `MemoryStream` to read bytes in as particular base types (*e.g.*, [`read_int16`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.DataInputStream.read_int16.html).

The gcrypt library's [`Hash`](https://valadoc.org/gcrypt/GCrypt.Hash.html) implementation supports [Blowfish](https://valadoc.org/gcrypt/GCrypt.Cipher.Algorithm.html).